# Add custom attribute to HTML tags

Tags: html

I am adding custom attributes to my HTMLtags something like

```
<li customeId="1">
```

I am to access this custom attribute in IE but in firefox, I am not able to get the values of these attributes. Any suggestion on how to access custom attribute in FireFox or any other way. I am using HTML 4 for development.

Code to access:

```
  var test =  licollection[index].customeId;
```

Thanks
Ashwani

Comment: How are you trying to access the attribute? Add the code, so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: You aren't using HTML 4. You are using tag soup. HTML 4 doesn't support custom attributes.

Comment: @David, then is there any other way to associate some properties with a tag in HTML 4?

Comment: Existing attributes. A script element containing some data (e.g. `var foo = { element_id: [1,2,3], other_element: [4,5,6] };). Text content.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hopefully below code will be helpful for you.

```
<div id="navigation">
 <ul>
  <li customerId="1"></li>
  <li customerId="2"></li>
  <li customerId="3"></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

```js
var x = document.getElementById('navigation');
if (!x) return;
var liCollections = x.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i=0;i<liCollections.length;i++)
   alert(liCollections[i].getAttribute('customerid', 0));
```

It's clear enough, and you can understand it easily.

Answer (score 9):

You can use HTML 5 `custom data attribute` functionality, it may helps you

**Attribute Name**

The data attribute name must be at least one character long and must be prefixed with **'data-'**. It should not contain any uppercase letters.

**Attribute Value**

The attribute value can be any string.

**Example :-**

```
<ul id="vegetable-seeds">
  <li data-spacing="10cm" data-sowing-time="March to June">Carrots</li>
  <li data-spacing="30cm" data-sowing-time="February to March">Celery</li>
  <li data-spacing="3cm" data-sowing-time="March to September">Radishes</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is great info. just a couple questions, 

> what will happen if the code runs on an old browser? (no HTML5 compatibility)

> is there a limit to 'data-<attrib>' tags >

Answer (score 2):

```
test.getAttribute('customerid');
```

Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var test = licollection[index].getAttribute("customeId");
```

Answer (score 0):

licollection[index].getAttribute("customeId")

reference: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Methods/getAttributeSyntaxParametersandNote.htm