# jQuerys $.data() vs. DOM Object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I recently needed to append some data to dynamically created `LI elements`. In my first instance, I used `.data()` in a way like

```
var _newli = $('<li>foobar</li>');
_newli.data('base', 'ball');
// append _newli to an `ul`
```

that.. was **terribly** slow. This logic happens in a loop which can easily grow up to 500+ items, it took ages! Sometimes it even broke the javascript execution time frame.

So I changed to `$.data()`. Somehow, attaching data to an object with that is like **8x** faster than doing it over the `.data()` method call. So now it looked like

```
var _newli = $('<li>foobar</li>');
$.data(_newli[0], 'base', 'ball');
// append _newli to an `ul`
```

That was/is indeed faster, but still it took like 3-4 seconds(!) to build up all my elements (In my real code there are like 6 calls to $.data per element).

So I was really stuck with that, I asked myself why the heck to use `.data()` or `$.data()` anyway? I could just attach my data to the `DOM object`. So I did

```
var _newli = $('<li>foobar</li>');
_newli[0].base = 'ball';
// append _newli to an `ul`
```

Voila, **wow** to my shock, that was incredibly fast! I couldn't believe that this ran so good without any disadvantage. So that is what is my question all about actually. I didn't find any disadvantage for this technique so far on the net. There are reads about **circular references** you can create using this way, but AFAIK "only" on IE's and only if you refer to `objects`.

Any thoughts experts ?

**update**

Thanks for the good comments and postings guys. Short update @patrick dw:

You are right, I was passing the underlaying `DOM element` when using `$.data()`. It does not even work with jQuery objects, at least not as expected.
The idea about using one object and pass it through `$.date()` I had myself, but then again I was so shocked about the performance difference I decided just to ignore the `.data()` method like forever.

Comment: If there were *"6 calls to $.data per element"*, is there a reason why you didn't just do one call, and pass in one object for the value that contains all the properties you want? `$.data(_newli,'myvalues',{'base':'ball','basket':'ball','foot':'ball'});`

Comment: In a talk, John said that it is slow, and suggests to do `var data = $('selector').data(); data['foo'] = 'bar'; data['bar'] = 'foo'; etc.`, so that you only have **one** access to it. just FYI.

Comment: @jAndy - You should be passing DOM elements to `$.data()`. Not `jQuery` objects. I wonder if that has a performance impact as well. `$.data(_newli[0], 'base', 'ball');`

Comment: @patrick dw: updated the post! @Felix Kling: Sounds pretty reasonable, do you know where I can find that Resig talk/paper? I'l give it a shot anyway, the big question there is, does it come close do the `DOM property storage`? Otherwise it's pretty useless anyway.

Comment: jAndy - I did a couple profiles with Webkit's profile tools, using @Felix's solution vs writing to the DOM element, assigning *one* property. *If I do not include the initial variable assignment in the test*, **data: 0.025ms, DOM: 0.040ms**. If I do include variable assignment for `data()`, `var data = $.data(_newli[0])`, it varies **data: 0.040ms to 0.225ms**. But this is for assigning one property. Assigning several properties will close some of that gap (when it exists). Using `$.data()` on 500 elements, at its slowest would be around 22ms. Pretty fast. Again, this is Webkit only.

Comment: @patrick dw: interesting, I should have mentioned it before that I experienced that performance issues on `FF 3.6.7`. Chrome with it's `V8` is way faster performing those operations. But good to know!

Comment: @jAndy Check out these jsperf stats: http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-getattribute/13 .
Fastest option is `el["searchable"] = true;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct about **circular references**, that isn't an issue outside of IE, and in IE it only becomes an issue when JavaScript has a reference to a DOM object, and a JS object is assigned to one of the DOM object's properties. I believe this can be resolved by simply by nullifying any references in JS to the DOM object.

The `$().data()` method is an overly complicated wrapper for `$.data()` (see `jQuery.fn.data`: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L126, which in turn calls `jQuery.data`: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L20), so cutting out that middle man will save a non trivial amount of time, especially if it's to be done 500 times.

In this case, the `$().data('foo', 'bar')` method doesn't do much more than `el.foo = 'bar'`. Do what's fastest.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to add custom properties to a NodeList object the browser (IE) might disallow it. See: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2010JanMar/0864.html

Answer (score 0):

These might help:

- [Can I just make up attributes on my HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427262/can-i-just-make-up-attributes-on-my-html-tags/)
- [Add custom attribute to HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824726/add-custom-attribute-to-html-tags)

And read the following on using a custom DTD:

- http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/customdtd.html

In short, for the most part I don't think you'll run into any problems using custom attributes. Most sensible/current browsers will fine with it. I will say, I *did* run into problems with a webapp I developed for MobileSafari, which forced me to resort to using <s>`$.data`</s> hidden elements. Fortunately, I did not have 500+ elements, but more like five or six.

Comment: I guess we're talking about two different storys. If you attach some data to `element.somedata = {foo: 5};` there is no `attribute` created for that. It's like mixing `ECMAland` and `DOMland` somehow, since an `DOM element` is treated like an object in ECMAscript.