# Is it faster to store data on a dom element with a class or jQuery data

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have a render loop that updates the status of a number of DOM elements on every iteration. The code must apply presentational classes to each element based on a value obtained from an external data source.

E.g.

```
var animationFrames = // Result of http get request

for (var i in animationFrames) {
    var frame = animationFrames[i];

    // This function reads data from the frame variable and updates
    // the presentational layer
    updateDomElements(frame);
}

var updateDomElements = function (frame) {
    var rooms = frame.rooms;

    for (var i in rooms) {
        var room = rooms[i];

        var roomEl = $(room.id);

        if (!roomEl.hasClass(room.class)) {
            roomEl.attr("class", room.class);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know what the most efficient way of storing presentational data in the DOM is? I'm worried that reading the class string on every iteration will be too expensive.

Would it be better to use the jQuery data() API and then set the class? Is there a more performant method that I haven't thought of?

Comment: I should clarify the problem... I need to update the class anyway, regardless of how the information is stored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't find my reference, but from what I remember using `$.data()` is the fastest (faster than `$(selector).data()`. jQuery stores the data in memory and doesn't use the DOM.

Any interaction with the DOM will be slower than accessing the data value in memory.

Edit: In the comments from jQuery.data()... here is a [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-jqueryselection-data) of `$.data()` vs `$(sel).data()` as well as slide 51 of [this presentation](http://paulirish.com/2009/perf/).

Edit 2: Here is another [nice discussion here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407634/jquerys-data-vs-dom-object-property). Especially read the comments by patrick dw!

Answer (score 4):

here is a test for it to try it yourself. Looks like $.data is the best.

http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-jquery-data